# Recursive relation practice

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, combinatorics-on-words

My questions:

Call a string of letters "legal" if it can be produced by concatenating (running together) copies of the following strings:
'v', 'ww', 'xx' 'yyy' and 'zzz'.
For example, the string 'xxvv' is legal because it can be produced by concatenating 'xx', 'v' and 'v', but the string 'xxxv' is not legal.

For each integer n≥1, let tn be the number of legal strings with n letters. For example, t1=1 ('v' is the only the legal string).

(a)

t2 = ?
My Answer = 3

t3 = ?
My Answer = 7

(b)
tn = atn−1 + btn−2 + ctn−3 for each integer n≥4

where a = ?  b = ?  c =?

My answer: a = 1, b = 2, c = 2

(c)
For each integer n≥1, let pn be the number of legal strings with n letters that also read the same right to left as they do left to right (like 'xxvxx', for example).

Which of the following expressions is equal to p101?

(a)t50+2t49
(b)t50+2t48
(c)t50+t48
(d)p50+p49
(e)p50+2p49
(f)p100+p99
(g)t50+t49
(h)t100+t99

Someone know how to solve question (c), not quite understand this question. And also someone can help me check if the answers for (a) and (b) are correct

Comment: What don't you understand about question $c$?  Also:  please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write mathematics on this site.

Comment: how to solve question c?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts (and to format your question properly).  I don't see anything confusing about $c$...perhaps you should start by computing $p_n$ for small $n$.

Answer (score 1):

For Question $(c)$-

For the string to palindromic and have $101$ characters, it must be of the form, $\underbrace{a_1a_2 \dots a_{50}} b_1 \underbrace{a_{50}a_{49} \dots a_{1}}$ or $\underbrace{a_1a_2 \dots a_{49}} b_1b_2b_3 \underbrace{a_{49}a_{48} \dots a_{1}}$. Using this, you can discover the reccurence relationship by considering the $a$ sequence and the $b$ sequence.

Comment: Is the answer (a)t50+2t49?